# Create a glossy light effect using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm trying to create a light effect with CSS and HTML only. Just like this image 
[image]

I don't know if it's possible. or how to do it.

Any help will be appreciated.

```css
.circle {
  border: 10px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is my example

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #393939 0%, #151515 100%);
  position: relative;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  width: 106px;
  height: 106px;
  border-radius: 53px;
  background: #19f000;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 7px;
  top: 7px;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-18deg);
  left: 13px;
  top: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ilyabogdanov/ogwh331s/)

Answer (score 6):

You can use a second `div` for the highlight to try and provide a stronger 3D effect, freeing up the `box-shadow` to be used for the darker contouring on the edges.

```css
.circle {
  width: 164px;
  height: 164px;
  background-color: #19f000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border: 10px solid #444444;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

.highlight {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: 64%;
  opacity: .92;
  border-radius: 100%;
  
  /* gratuitous gradient compatibility - activate! */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
<div class="highlight"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do with the combination of `radial gradient` and a pseudo element for glossy effect.

1. The transition from white to green can be produced through radial-gradient. The #fff color stops at 5%.
2. The glossy effect finish is given using the `opacity` on the pseudo element and has a similar shape of the parent with white background and reduced width.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2sjkbd4s/)

```css
.circle::after {
  background: white none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0.15;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  left: 20px;
}
.circle {
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50px 10px , #ffffff 0%, #fff 5%, #00ff00 100%);
  border: 10px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">

</div>
```

Comment: Oopss, should've refreshed the page earlier and seen that you've already used `radial-gradient` :( But I'll leave my answer there as this can be done using a single element. +1 to you.

Comment: No problem Harry. I liked your answer better i.e. limiting the lines of code.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using a single element also by layering one `radial-gradient` image of the required size on top of an angled `linear-gradient` image and then positioning it appropriately. Multiple background images and layering has very good browser support (IE9+) but gradients are supported only in IE10+.

```css
.circle {
  border: 10px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 90px 45px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75) 10%, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 30%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 32%, rgba(25,240,0,1) 45%), linear-gradient(160deg, transparent 12%, rgb(25, 240, 0) 30%);
  background-size: 125% 80%, 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

---

**Browser Compatibility Charts:**

- [Multiple background images and layering](http://caniuse.com/multibackgrounds)
- [Gradients](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.circle {
    border:10px solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px; 
    background: rgb(25,240,0); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(25,240,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(25,240,0,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(25,240,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(25,240,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(25,240,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to top,  rgba(25,240,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#19f000', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
</style>
<head>
<body>
<div class="circle">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please use background gradient color as mentioned above. i hope this woould helpful to you

here is the working demo.[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UIweb/v7aLzvb1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try box shadow like this: **[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kbcqfwep/2/)**

Adjust the **shadow** values and **background gradient colors** according to your need.

```
 .circle {
    border:10px solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #f8ffe8;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;
    base64, PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2Y4ZmZlOCIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjE3JSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzU2YmM2YyIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMxOTliMDAiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f8ffe8 0%, #56bc6c 17%, #199b00 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #f8ffe8), color-stop(17%, #56bc6c), color-stop(100%, #199b00));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f8ffe8 0%, #56bc6c 17%, #199b00 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f8ffe8 0%, #56bc6c 17%, #199b00 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f8ffe8 0%, #56bc6c 17%, #199b00 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f8ffe8 0%, #56bc6c 17%, #199b00 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f8ffe8', endColorstr='#199b00', GradientType=0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1px 60px 68px -28px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -1px 60px 68px -28px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    box-shadow: inset -1px 60px 68px -28px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```