# How to make gradient like glow in corner of a div

Tags: css, reactjs, gradient

[image]

I am trying to make a gradient like glow in a corner of a div like in a photo above ( color is not important )

I've tried:

```
<div style={{ background: `linear-gradient(#f79800,#03A678)` }}>
  <Icon/>
</div>
```

```css
.icon-wrapper {
  background: linear-gradient(#f79800, #03A678);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="icon-wrapper">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-umbrella"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: FWIW this seems to have nothing to do with anything other than the CSS; consider just showing the rendered HTML for this instead.

Comment: I added a snippet demo. Does it accurately represent your situation?

Comment: And are you asking about a glow or about a _reflection_?

Comment: @isherwood That is my situation. I am trying to achieve that curved white glow in top left corner of div

Comment: It's a glossy reflection, not a glow. You'll get better results if you search that, and it's been covered thoroughly already.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are trying to get a "glassy look" (to give you a keyword to search for).

**edit** , the right keyword is glossy (excuse my average english) - a duplicate that seems fine to your needs : [Create a glossy light effect using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33359979/create-a-glossy-light-effect-using-css)

You may then see if adding a translucide radial-gradient on top of the linear-gradient does the job.

possible example to tune:

```css
.icon-wrapper {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at top left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25) 40%, transparent 45%), linear-gradient(#f79800, #03A678);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius:0.3em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="icon-wrapper">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-umbrella"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you might adjust the code to create a "glow" effect in the top right corner of the div:
Please try this :

```
<div style={{ 
    background: `linear-gradient(135deg, #f79800, #03A678, #f79800)`,
    background: `-webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #f79800, #03A678, #f79800)`,
    background: `-o-linear-gradient(135deg, #f79800, #03A678, #f79800)`,
    background: `-moz-linear-gradient(135deg, #f79800, #03A678, #f79800)`
  }}>
  <Icon/>
</div>
```

Comment: None of those vendor prefixes are necessary in 2023. See https://caniuse.com/css-gradients.

Answer (score 0):

I think :after pseudo could help you to have a transparent cover over your background so you can achieve your aims like that,

here you can find an example of what you aims to get.
i wish it helps

```css
div {
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
  background:radial-gradient(coral,lightpink);
  border:3px solid lightgray;
  border-radius:15px;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  align-content:center;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  font-size:8rem;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:cursive;
}
div:after {
  content:"";
  height:140px;
  width:140px;
  position:absolute;
  background:linear-gradient(45deg, white,lightgray);
  opacity:0.1;
  border-radius:15px;
  margin:5px;
}
span {
  color: lightgray;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
}
```

```html
<div><span>&copy;</span></div>
```